# Independence of first coin toss and second coin toss

Tags: probability

I was doing this problem:

> Two coins are in a hat. The coins look alike, but one coin is fair (with probability 1/2 of Heads), while the other coin is biased, with probability 1/4 of Heads. One of the coins is randomly pulled from the hat, without knowing which of the two it is. Call the chosen coin “Coin C”

> b) Are the events "first toss of Coin C is Heads" and "second toss of Coin C is Heads" independent? Explain.

(from [here](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_2.pdf))

My first intuition was that they are independent, because a toss of any given coin is not going to affect the outcome of any other toss. This turns out to be wrong:

> They’re not independent: the first toss being Heads is evidence in favor of the
> coin being the fair coin, giving information about probabilities for the second toss.

Which makes sense, because in this case, we don't know if the coin is fair or not, so knowing the outcome of the first toss affects the probability of the second toss. I was able to make sense of the solution by thinking that the two events are *conditionally independent* given information about the coin's bias (i.e., that it is fair or not).

I then think of situations outside this problem. Say I have a coin, and I don't know whether the coin is fair or not. This seems to be the same situation as in the problem, so coin tosses in real life are actually, strictly speaking, not independent, but they are conditionally independent on our knowledge of the (level of) fairness of the coin.

Is this thinking correct? In addition, this seems to lend itself to Bayesian interpretation of probability. Is there a way to formulate this in frequentist terms?

Comment: I think you are confusing between a given coin's throws being independent (it clearly is, e.g. the biased coin will continue independently to give heads with Pr = 1/4) and trying to ascertain whether the coin being rolled  is  biased or fair depending on the sequence rolled, where Rev Bayes will come in.

Comment: @trueblueanil Right, but what does "a given coin's throws being independent" mean? Does it mean that "the ith toss of the coin is Heads" and "the i+1th toss of the coin is Heads" are independent? If that's the case, why are the events in the question not independent? The event descriptions are "the first toss of coin C is Heads" and "the second toss of coin C is Heads"; these are the same coin. 

If they are not independent because we don't know whether coin C is biased or not, then why shouldn't this apply to just coins in general, whose bias I don't know?

Comment: I guess I was thinking along these lines: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447383/is-independence-subjective